# More than 3 elements on WearableListView

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm building an Android Wear application and on a given screen I've a picker in form of a WearableListView. It is my understanding that this class is closed source. Does anyone know how to have more than 3 elements displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 4):

Seing exactly three elements is done by design. Our goal was to not overwhelm the user with information on a small screen. Beside that the center element has a special meaning, because it's clickable. If you change the value to say 4, it wouldn't be as clear, which item is clickable. On top of that, the item below and above also have a special behavior - if you click them, the list will scroll to them.

So please, don't do it differently. `WearableListView` is used everywhere inside Android Wear. It is well understood by users by now. If you change how it behaves, you will only introduce confusion.

Comment: It seems like a weird design though. The class has a name akin to ListView, i.e very generic. However, it enforces a specific behavior for very specific purposes. It's ok for action lists, menus etc. But what if a wearable is a Pip-boy with a big screen? Or we need to display items of different heights? Or I want to follow this paradigm, but want the focused item to take 80% of the screen and I don't care about items above and below to be fully shown? All I'm saying this class should be named like WearableThreeItemListView and be a subclass of a more generic and flexible WearableListView.

Comment: If you need more generic and flexible, there is a base class that WearableListView uses, it's RecyclerView. You can use it to achieve all the goals you are describing. We didn't see any point in packaging all this functionality into a subclass. Instead of wanted to achieve a consistent experience when using lists in applications. We don't want the user to think, what kind of behavior the list will have. If you really think you need something custom, the RecyclerView allows you to do much more.

Comment: Sure, that's what I'm using. Just saying, given the knowledge devs have about ListView class, WearableListView name is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The number `3` seems to be pretty hardcoded in `WearableListView`. Check for example the implementation of `computeTapRegions()` or, for the clearest example:

```
private int getItemHeight() {
    return getAdjustedHeight() / 3;
}
```

It doesn't seem to have been designed to allow the programmer to display a different number of items at once.

That being said, you might try decompiling its source (from inside the aar) and altering it for this purpose. Not sure if that would actually be legal, though.